# View Details link in Chrome Extension abandons inline installation, pops details under. Can this change?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension to Google Chrome that generally works properly.  When I invite my user to do inline installation, everything seems to work, except for one thing.

If my user clicks the Chrome-furnished Show Details link, two things happen:

-- Chrome behaves like the user cancelled the installation.
  -- The Chrome Store page pops under the inline installation page in a new tab.

This leaves my user wondering what happened.

Is there a way to modify this behavior, so the "more information" is shown to the user, and the installation is not cancelled?

It looks like this:  Here's the install prompt
[image: screenshot of inline extension install]

Upon clicking the View Details link in the install dialog, this happens.
[image: wrongly-cancelled inline install]

Notice the new third tab, behind the current tab, containing my extension's Google Store page.

Comment: do you have any screenshots demonstrating this behaviour? it may be easier to see what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's any antivirus program or a similar Windows firewall-esque feature that is preventing the installation. Try isolating the problem by turning off one firewall or antivirus, running the installation, and reactivating that firewall or antivirus so not to let down all of your shields at once for prolonged periods of time. [Source.](https://serato.com/forum/discussion/995473)

You may report this if you think this is a bug.

> To submit a bug or a feature request on DevTools, please use issue tracker at http://crbug.com. Please also mention "DevTools" in the bug summary.

Hope this helps!